# scroll-snap with react 17

Tags: reactjs, scroll-snap

I am trying to use scroll-snap in react v17 with styled-components, but I cant get it to work. I found [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/n2ynjj8lj?file=/src/index.js:161-416) project what works in react v16.8 and it is written in class components. I am trying to write it in function component.
Here is my function component code:

```
  const container = useRef(0);

  const scrollSnap = () => {
    const element = container.current;
    createScrollSnap(
      element,
      {
        snapDestinationY: "90%"
      },
      () => console.log("snapped")
    );
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    scrollSnap();
  }, [container]);
```

Here is working project that I found on [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/n2ynjj8lj?file=/src/index.js:161-416), written in class components:

```
  container = React.createRef()

  bindScrollSnap() {
    const element = this.container.current
    createScrollSnap(element, {
      snapDestinationY: '90%',
    }, () => console.log('snapped'))
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.bindScrollSnap()
  }
```

Comment: How about using [native CSS scroll-snap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-snap-type)?

Comment: I am using styled-components.